# Converting USD model into GLTF file format

Tags: arkit, arcore, gltf, usdz

I've been looking for a way to convert `.usdc` / `.usda` / `.usdz` files into `.gltf` using a command line, Python, node, whatever...

Been looking at every solutions so far, could find some `.gltf` to `.usd` converter but no `.usd` to `.gltf`. Is anyone aware of anything?

Answer (score 1):

Use online [USDZ to GLTF](https://products.groupdocs.app/conversion/usdz-to-gltf) Converter. To view a result, use online [glTF Viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JavaScript you can use [three-usdz-loader](https://github.com/ponahoum/three-usdz-loader) to load the model into three.js and then you can export into gltf [GLTFExporter](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/exporters/GLTFExporter).

If you're looking for an online client-side only solution with an inbuilt viewer and editor you may try [gltfeditor](https://gltfeditor.com). It can load and export glTF, glb, USDZ and a few other formats.

[image]

Disclaimer: it's built by me, it's a free tool that you can use without registration.